# How to record clash of clans so that my voice is loud but the sound for the game is low?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am using recordable apps to record clash of clans.

However, my voice is not heard. Buried behind music.

I want the voice and music of clash of clans to be loud and my comments are more clearly heard..

Comment: Give us the links of the "recordable apps" you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Lowering the sound volume in android does not lower the sound of my voice.

So it works.

I seem to be using this except that I am using the paid version (only $1)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.org.invisibility.recordablefree&hl=en

However, it works for other things too.